# Trying to bind TextBlock which is inside the DataTemplate of an accordion control in Silverlight. Text is not visible when I run the application

Tags: silverlight, binding, user-controls, datatemplate, accordion

I amsomewhat new to Silverlight, What I want to do is to show the Title in the accordion control which is bound from the property of that user control. I have a TextBlock which is inside the DataTemplate of an Accordion control in Silverlight. When I run the application, text is coming blank and nothing is displayed in the Accordion title.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.SilverlightControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:layoutToolkit="clr-     namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <layoutToolkit:Accordion x:Name="accordionFilter" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="ZeroOrMore">
            <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem MinHeight="0" MaxHeight="120" IsSelected="True">
                <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock
                                    Text="{Binding MainPageSelectedText}" 
                                    Width="150"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </layoutToolkit:AccordionItem.HeaderTemplate>
            </layoutToolkit:AccordionItem>
        </layoutToolkit:Accordion>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>



using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class SilverlightControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler ph = this.PropertyChanged;

            if (ph != null)
                ph(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public SilverlightControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPageSelectedText = "Sample Text";
        }

        public string MainPageSelectedText
        {
            get { return _MainPageSelectedText; }
            set
            {
                string myValue = value ?? String.Empty;
                if (_MainPageSelectedText != myValue)
                {
                    _MainPageSelectedText = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MainPageSelectedText");
                }
            }
        }
        private string _MainPageSelectedText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your data template level you don't have direct access to the user control's DataContext so your binding should look sth like:

`Text="{Binding MainPageSelectedText, ElementName=MyUserControl}"`

assuming that you will set Name/x:Name of your user control to **MyUserControl**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the quick reply. That is what I was missing. Even it works without the INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Comment: Yes, because you set the value before it is bound (in the constructor). If you wanted to change the title in the runtime, INotifyPropertyChanged (or dependency property) would be required.